# Purging previous versions of functions when developing packages in R

Tags: r, package

I am developing a package in R.  Let's call it `mypkg`.

Because some functions behave differently when they are run from a package (I am not sure why--but this is not the question), I am editing functions in the package, then rebuilding the package from the command line.  For some reason a given R instance retains older versions of the functions even though the source has been changed and the package rebuilt and re-installed.  I need to start a new instance to see the changes.

Here is the typical workflow.

1. Make changes to `myfunction()` in `mypkg.R`
2. In R:  `detach(package:mypkg); remove.packages("mypkg")`
3. Command line: `R CMD INSTALL --build c:\mypkg`
4. Notifies me that it has been installed to the default library
5. In R: `library(mypkg)`
6. In R: `myfunction()` runs the previous version before changes.

[The next three steps I want to avoid]

1. Start a new R instance
2. In R: `library(mypkg)`
3. `myfunction()` works as expected

Run under R.2.14.1.

I am looking for suggestions of how to improve this workflow to avoid starting a new R instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to try to unload the package as well as detach it. `?detach` has:

> If a package has a namespace, detaching it does not by default
>   unload the namespace (and may not even with ‘unload=TRUE’), and
>   detaching will not in general unload any dynamically loaded
>   compiled code (DLLs).  Further, registered S3 methods from the
>   namespace will not be removed.  If you use ‘library’ on a package
>   whose namespace is loaded, it attaches the exports of the already
>   loaded namespace.  So detaching and re-attaching a package may not
>   refresh some or all components of the package, and is inadvisable.

Note the last sentence in particular.

Try:

```
detach(package:mypkg, unload = TRUE)
```

Note that the "If a package has a namespace" now means all packages as this was changed in R 2.14.0 (IIRC the version number)

If the code you are changing is R code, consider using `assignInNamespace()` to assign an object/function in your global workspace (i.e. the newer version of function in `mypkg`) to the namespace of `mypkg`. For example we have function `foo()` in `mypkg` and locally we have `newfoo()` which is the newer version of `foo()`:

```
assignInNamespace("foo", newfoo, "mypkg")
```

If the changes relate to C code, or the above don't work, then perhaps you should follow the advice of R Core and spawn a new R instance instead of trying to detach your package.

See also the **devtools** package of Hadley Wickham and Emacs+ESS might make the development process easier (spawning new R instances etc) if you speak Emacs.

Comment: `detach(package:mypkg, unload=TRUE)` of course, works perfectly.  I have been avoiding learning about these new namespace things.  Looks as if I can avoid it no longer.